# Font size increases button volume. What is the correct behaviour?

Tags: html, css

I have a button , well .. actually a `<li>` acting as one. I shape it with the padding without giving it any height. For a click effect, I set font increase +1 on active. Now, on Firefox it expands the button, which is not what I want. On Chromium it does it right and keeps the button size constant while increasing the font size. I can fix this with setting the buttons height - no problem. Although it is not ideal.

But I am just wondering what is the correct behaviour? Should the font size expand the button or should it not?

I assumed that with IE out of the way, two compliant browsers should agree on how to render stuff in common scenarios.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I do apologise for not including the CSS. I thought the wording is simple enough. Here is the sample ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Basal</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="base2.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li> Create </li>
        <li> Read </li>
        <li> Update </li>
        <li> Delete </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS ...

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid #232B2B;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

nav ul li {
  flex: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 2px solid #232B2B;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #685642;
  font-size: 16px;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: #74695C;
}

nav ul li:active {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

In Firefox, It expands the `<li>` container every time I click it. In Chromium - it does not. In Chromium it just increases the font size keeping the container size constant.

Firefox - 28.0
Chromium -  34.0.1847.116 (260972)

Comment: Why not put a real button <button> on the page, apply the same scripts to it and see what happens?

Comment: You should show the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code. The verbal description is too vague. For example, “font increase +1” is ambiguous – do you mean an increase of 1cm, or 1pt, or 1px, or what?

Comment: @jeff This is not what I am questioning here. What I am wondering about is why the behaviour is not the same in both browsers and what is the correct way to render it in this particular situation.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela I added the update with both HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of an element generally depends on the height requirements of its content. The details have intentionally been left browser-dependent in CSS specifications. Increasing font size may or may not increase the height requirements; typically, an increase of 1px does not, an increase of 2px does.

For the given code, both Firefox and Chrome (34.0.1847.131, Win 7) increase the height of the `li` element when it is activated. The difference is that on Chrome, the increased height remains even when the element returns from active state to normal state. This is probably unintentional and might be classified as a bug. (The effect can perhaps be seen better if you add `:active { background: red }`.)

In general, you should not expect different browsers to assign the same height to an element unless you explicitly set the height.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Chromium expands the container on the first click and then just keeps it constant. Firefox expands and shrinks it on every click. I did not notice it with one pixel increment, it is noticeable with +2 pixels though. Bug it is then or just weird behaviour on the part of Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

If you're increasing the font size, it would make sense that when the font gets large enough, the "li" container will also have to increase its size to keep it contained.

Answer (score 0):

I test your question in chrome, and it does the same as it in Firefox.When you set font increase +1 on active, you must set the active button's attribute "padding-top" or "padding-bottom" decrease the same size.
Browser calculate button's height as follows:
height=margin-top+border-top+padding-top+height+padding-bottom+border-bottom+margin-bottom
You can search CSS box model to see more detail.

Comment: Not in my case unfortunately. Given the above CSS and HTML, the browsers render it differently. I added the versions for both browsers.